# Magento 2.4.4 upgrade error on composer update

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, magento2.4.4

Magento 2.4.4 trying to composer update and getting below error

[image: Magento 2.4.4 trying to update and getting below error]

Can anyone please suggest some solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Run below commands**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update

composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento s:d:c

php bin/magento in:rein

php bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but when going to fire the command 
"composer update --ignore-platform-reqs" getting attached image error. https://ibb.co/kDnjwmt

Comment: @Yogesh please run all commands in a given sequence.

Comment: tried same but on the second command its showing above error as attached on last comment

Comment: @Yogesh please check I got this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355385/upgrade-magento-2-4-3-to-2-4-4-get-404-note-found

Comment: tried same as like mentioned in the link but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem upgrading from 2.4.2 to 2.4.4

I follow the commands from both Adobe and Above

1. composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update
   Response:
   /public$ composer update
   Loading composer repositories with package information
2. composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
   Response:

   Loading composer repositories with package information
   Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
   In Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterV2::onPrePoolCreate
   Updating dependencies
   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.4].
- Conclusion: don't install ramsey/uuid 4.2.2 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install ramsey/uuid 4.2.3 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.3.0 (conflict analysis result)
- allure-framework/allure-codeception[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.1] require codeception/codeception ^2.3|^3.0 -> satisfiable by codeception/codeception[2.3.0, ..., 2.5.6, 3.0.0, ..., 3.1.3].
- codeception/codeception[2.4.1, ..., 2.5.6] require codeception/phpunit-wrapper ^6.0.9|^7.0.6 -> satisfiable by codeception/phpunit-wrapper[6.0.9, ..., 6.8.4, 7.0.6, ..., 7.8.4].
- codeception/codeception 2.4.0 requires codeception/phpunit-wrapper ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by codeception/phpunit-wrapper[6.0.0, ..., 6.8.4, 7.0.0, ..., 7.8.4].
- codeception/codeception[3.0.0, ..., 3.1.3] require codeception/phpunit-wrapper >6.0.15 <6.1.0 | ^6.6.1 | ^7.7.1 | ^8.0.3 -> satisfiable by codeception/phpunit-wrapper[6.0.16, ..., 6.8.4, 7.7.1, ..., 7.8.4, 8.0.3, ..., 8.1.6].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 requires magento/framework 103.0.4 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[103.0.4].
- codeception/phpunit-wrapper[6.0.0, ..., 6.0.10] require phpunit/phpunit >=4.8.28 <5.0.0 || >=5.6.3 <7.0 -> found phpunit/phpunit[4.8.28, ..., 4.8.36, 5.6.3, ..., 5.7.27, 6.0.0, ..., 6.5.14] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/codeception[2.3.7, ..., 2.3.9] require phpunit/phpunit >=4.8.28 <5.0.0 || >=5.6.3 <7.0 -> found phpunit/phpunit[4.8.28, ..., 4.8.36, 5.6.3, ..., 5.7.27, 6.0.0, ..., 6.5.14] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/phpunit-wrapper[6.0.2, 7.0.0, ..., 7.0.6] require phpunit/phpunit ^7.0 -> found phpunit/phpunit[7.0.0, ..., 7.5.20] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/phpunit-wrapper[6.0.11, ..., 6.0.12] require phpunit/phpunit >=5.7.27 <7.0 -> found phpunit/phpunit[5.7.27, 6.0.0, ..., 6.5.14] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/phpunit-wrapper[6.0.13, ..., 6.1.3] require phpunit/phpunit >=5.7.27 <6.5.13 -> found phpunit/phpunit[5.7.27, 6.0.0, ..., 6.5.12] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/phpunit-wrapper[6.0.15, 7.7.0, ..., 7.8.4] require phpunit/phpunit 7.5.* -> found phpunit/phpunit[7.5.0, ..., 7.5.20] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/phpunit-wrapper[6.1.0, ..., 6.8.4] require phpunit/phpunit >=6.5.13 <7.0 -> found phpunit/phpunit[6.5.13, 6.5.14] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/phpunit-wrapper[7.1.0, ..., 7.1.4] require phpunit/phpunit ^7.1 -> found phpunit/phpunit[7.1.0, ..., 7.5.20] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/phpunit-wrapper 7.2.0 requires phpunit/phpunit ~7.1.0|~7.2.0 -> found phpunit/phpunit[7.1.0, ..., 7.2.7] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/phpunit-wrapper[7.3.0, ..., 7.3.2] require phpunit/phpunit ~7.1.0|~7.2.0|~7.3.0 -> found phpunit/phpunit[7.1.0, ..., 7.3.5] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/phpunit-wrapper 7.4.0 requires phpunit/phpunit >=7.1 <7.5 -> found phpunit/phpunit[7.1.0, ..., 7.4.5] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/phpunit-wrapper[7.5.0, ..., 7.6.1] require phpunit/phpunit >=7.1 <7.6 -> found phpunit/phpunit[7.1.0, ..., 7.5.20] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/phpunit-wrapper[8.0.3, ..., 8.1.6] require phpunit/phpunit ^8.0 -> found phpunit/phpunit[8.0.0, ..., 8.5.27] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/codeception 2.3.0 requires phpunit/phpunit >4.8.20 <6.0 -> found phpunit/phpunit[4.8.21, ..., 4.8.36, 5.0.0, ..., 5.7.27] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- codeception/codeception[2.3.1, ..., 2.3.6] require phpunit/phpunit >4.8.20 <7.0 -> found phpunit/phpunit[4.8.21, ..., 4.8.36, 5.0.0, ..., 5.7.27, 6.0.0, ..., 6.5.14] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9).
- Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.0.0, ..., 3.10.0].
- allure-framework/allure-phpunit[1.2.0, ..., 1.2.3] require allure-framework/allure-php-api ~1.1.0 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.1.0, ..., 1.1.8].
- You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.1.0, ..., 1.4.0].
- Conclusion: don't install one of allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.2.1], allure-framework/allure-phpunit[1.2.4] (conflict analysis result)
- allure-framework/allure-codeception 1.4.5 requires allure-framework/allure-php-api ~1.2.1 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.2.1].
- magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.3.0 requires allure-framework/allure-codeception ~1.4.0 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-codeception[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.5].
- allure-framework/allure-codeception[1.4.3, ..., 1.4.4] require allure-framework/allure-php-api ~1.1.8 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.1.8].
- allure-framework/allure-codeception 1.4.2 requires allure-framework/allure-php-api ~1.1.7 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.1.7, 1.1.8].
- allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.1.6, ..., 1.1.8] require ramsey/uuid ^3.0 -> satisfiable by ramsey/uuid[3.0.0, ..., 3.9.6].
- allure-framework/allure-php-api 1.1.5 requires ramsey/uuid ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by ramsey/uuid[3.0.0, ..., 3.9.6].
- Only one of these can be installed: rhumsaa/uuid[2.7.0, ..., 2.8.2], ramsey/uuid[3.0.0, ..., 3.9.6, 4.0.0, ..., 4.3.1]. ramsey/uuid replaces rhumsaa/uuid and thus cannot coexist with it.
- magento/framework 103.0.4 requires ramsey/uuid ~4.2.0 -> satisfiable by ramsey/uuid[4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3].
- Conclusion: don't install ramsey/uuid 4.2.1 (conflict analysis result)
- Root composer.json requires allure-framework/allure-phpunit ~1.2.0 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-phpunit[1.2.0, ..., 1.2.4].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
storm02:~/public$ ^C

cheers,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

im getting this problem after the 2nd command, Any help please

composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.4].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 requires colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis 1.14.2 -> found colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis[1.14.2] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (1.11.0).
Problem 2
- composer/composer[1.9.0, ..., 1.9.3] require symfony/finder ^2.7 || ^3.0 || ^4.0 -> found symfony/finder[v2.7.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.44] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^5.2).
- Root composer.json requires magento/composer 1.6.0 -> satisfiable by magento/composer[1.6.0].
- magento/composer 1.6.0 requires composer/composer ^1.9 -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.9.0, ..., 1.10.26].
- composer/composer[1.10.0, ..., 1.10.26] require composer/semver ^1.0 -> satisfiable by composer/semver[1.0.0, ..., 1.7.2].
- You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: composer/semver[1.0.0, ..., 1.7.2, 2.0.0, 3.0.0, ..., 3.3.2].
- friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer v3.4.0 requires composer/semver ^3.2 -> satisfiable by composer/semver[3.2.0, ..., 3.3.2].
- Root composer.json requires friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer ~3.4.0 -> satisfiable by friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer[v3.4.0].