# Upgrade magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.4 get 404 Note Found

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.4, upgrade, 404-page, magento2.4.4

**I run the below commands. after that in the terminal, Magento commands run well but on the other end, it's given me a 404 Not Found error in the browser frontend and backend.**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update

composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento s:d:c

php bin/magento in:rein

php bin/magento c:c
```

[image]

**404 Not Found:** https://prnt.sc/uDcoYMkJPdro

**And URL path is already set proper in core_config_data table:** https://prnt.sc/oMATtMkqsojb

How to solve this? Anyone can help me?

Comment: try adding pub at the end of the base_url like this localhost/m24data/pub

Comment: is it be 1)composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update 2) composer update command run successfully?

Comment: Yes @S.P  it's run perfectly.

Comment: You had already created virtual host for your side right?

Answer (score 0):

Did you start elasticsearch, setup 2FA?
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/security/two-factor-authentication.html#magento-functional-testing-framework

Did you check cookie domain in core_config_data table?

Comment: elasticsearch service is running well and 2FA is disabled for now. In core_config_data each entry is proper.

Answer (score -1):

you can add pub at the end of the base_url Secure and unsecure http://127.0.0.1/m24data/pub/

OR

You can use virtual host so no needed the add pub in base URL.

Follow this URL for create virtual host for ubuntu

https://programmingfields.com/how-to-create-virtual-host-ubuntu-20-04-for-apache-server/

After added the pub run below all command

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml rm -rf pub/static/_cache rm -rf var/cache rm -rf var/composer_home rm -rf var/generation rm -rf var/generated rm -rf var/page_cache rm -rf var/view_preprocessed rm -rf var/log rm -rf var/report rm -rf generated/code/ rm -rf generated/metadata/

php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media/ pub/static/
```

Comment: It's we do not use a virtual host. After adding the pub run Magento command nothing is working. same 404 page not found

Comment: See the updated the answer and it's working fine.

Comment: after running all commands nothing is solved.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding pub at the end of the base_url like this
http://localhost/m24data/pub